# Запарсить ссылку из таблицы в википедии на python

Tags: python, парсер, beautiful-soup

```
r = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers)

with open("index.html", "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    file.write(r.text)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")

tables = soup.find_all("div", class_="table-wide")

for table in tables:
    table = table.find_all("div", class_="table-wide-inner").find("table", class_="sortable wikitable jquery-tablesorter")

    for weapon_url in table:
        weapon_url = weapon_url.find("tbody").find("tr").find("td").find("a").get("href")
        print(weapon_url)
```

Код выводит ничего, в питоне не силен, если не получится попробую на C# написать, заранее всем спасибо. Ссылка на сайт с которого парсил - https://eldenring.fandom.com/wiki/Weapons?so=search

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На странице код генерируется при помощи JS поэтому для парсинга предлагаю использовать selenium + BS. Если получить контент с помощью selenium то проблема в Вашем коде в том, что `weapon_url = weapon_url.find("tbody").find("tr").find("td").find("a").get("href")` вернёт только первую ссылку из массива и она будет ссылаться на изображение, вот пример:`href="https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/eldenring/images/2/2e/ER_Icon_weapon_Battle_Axe.png/revision/latest?cb=20220411004827"`. В Вашем случае вы хотите вернуть все ссылки на оружие, поэтому предлагаю такое решение, оно не самое элегантное но рабочее. В конце мы собираем все ссылки включая те, что я упомянул выше, поэтому мы их фильтруем по условию и выводим только ссылки, которые нас интересуют, предварительно передав названия домена для полноты ссылки. А вот собственно и код:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


url = f'https://eldenring.fandom.com/wiki/Weapons?so=search'

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.82 Safari/537.36",
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
}

def get_result(url, headers):

    chrome_options = Options()
    # chrome_options.binary_location = "/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome"
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options, executable_path=".../chromedriver_linux64/chromedriver") # the path to your chromedriver
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(10)  # You can wait until the page loads, but it's easier to wait 10 seconds, they will be enough with a margin
    html = driver.page_source
    
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
    tables = soup.find_all("div", class_="table-wide")

    for table in tables:
        table = table.find_all("table", class_="sortable wikitable jquery-tablesorter")
        for trs in table:
            trs = trs.find("tbody").find_all("tr")
            for tds in trs:
                tds = tds.find_all("td")
                for weapon_url in tds:
                    try:
                        weapon_url = weapon_url.find("a").get("href")
                        if weapon_url[0:5]=='https':
                            pass
                        else:
                            print(f'https://eldenring.fandom.com{weapon_url}')
                    except AttributeError:
                        pass
                


def main():
    get_result(url=url, headers=headers)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Возвращает:

```
https://eldenring.fandom.com/wiki/Battle_Axe
https://eldenring.fandom.com/wiki/Celebrant%27s_Cleaver
https://eldenring.fandom.com/wiki/Forked_Hatchet
https://eldenring.fandom.com/wiki/Hand_Axe
https://eldenring.fandom.com/wiki/Highland_Axe
https://eldenring.fandom.com/wiki/Icerind_Hatchet
https://eldenring.fandom.com/wiki/Iron_Cleaver
https://eldenring.fandom.com/wiki/Jawbone_Axe
https://eldenring.fandom.com/wiki/Ripple_Blade
https://eldenring.fandom.com/wiki/Rosus%27_Axe
......
```